# NumberFormat.format(String) does compile

Tags: java

I tested the following java code :

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
System.out.println(nf.format("15"));
```

How come this code compiles, when there is no method in javadoc that have the signature format(String s)?

Comment: But there is inherited [`format(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format-java.lang.Object-) which can accept any Object including String.

Comment: @Pshemo: yep, in the parent abstract [java.text.Format class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parent java.text.Format there is a method `public final String format(Object obj)`. And you can use it with String because Object is a parent class to String.

Comment: so basically, it will always compile and always throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @JachkE Unfortunately yes since String is also Object so it matches expected argument type. `format` is supposed to format any numeric type to String but not vice-versa. For opposite functionality we use `parse`.